# Multi Select Customer Group Promotion Price Rules Not Applied

Tags: catalog-price-rules, customer-group

I have converted the `Customer Group` from `Select` to `multi-select` by following the below URL,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528327/assign-customer-to-multiple-customer-groups-to-magento,

it's working fine.

My Problem is when a customer associated with more than 1 customer group then the Promotion pricing rules are not applied to that customer.

Eg. If a Customer `A` has a customer group `General` and `Wholesale`,
I have created a Promotion price rule for Customer Group `General`, then the pricing rules need to apply to the customer A,`but the price rules are not applied to that Customer A`(this is my problem).

If I assign Customer group as only `General`, then price rules are applied to Customer `A`.

I need if customer A has more than 1 customer group, then the Price Rules should be applied.

Answer (score 2):

CustomerGroup is a select field and I'm sure everywhere is checked for ONE value.

e.g. here `\Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::init`

this means, everywhere where magento expects `(int)7` you pass either `(array) [0] => (int) 1, [1] => (int) 2, [2] => (int)3` or `(string)1,2,3,4` and both is wrong.

Magento is not built to use more than one customer group and you can change this setting, then it may work on some places, but on MOST places you get a lot of problems.

TL;DR You want to invest a lot of money to fix all problems or just revert/let it as it is.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Fabian, the value i got value 2,3 for single assign i got 2, so its working correctly for single assignment, but when assigning more than 1 value i getting problem. but i need this feature. what is your suggestion?

Comment: There is no real solution for this. You can rewrite the whole group system, which will take a while (I would plan at least 10 days), the alternative is, to create n! (n factorial) customer groups, so you can choose the right for each customer, but depending on the amount of your customer groups then you might ran into indexing issues. So the solution depends hard on your environment.

Comment: thanks @Fabian for your suggestion. but i need this feature because i have already worked more than 2 weeks based on this feature.

Comment: If you want your customer group to stay as it is, you have to rewrite the rule system which checks the membership to a customer group...